# Eliminate Render Blocking Resources / Reduce Unused JavaScript

Tags: css, reactjs, web, vite

I know there are tons of content on how to achieve that but I have a specific question. Might seem like an easy issue but I'm using PageSpeed Insights and get those recomendations. Now, the problem is, that Google indicates two files, which are unexistant in my codebase, instead they're created during Vite build. Namely /assets/index-(identifier).js and /assets/index-(identifier).css

[Here is what I get from PageSpeed Insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NtFM.png)

I tried Coverage tab too but still nothing indicated which file was causing this slow down actually. Any advise on addressing which files exactly cause this issue?